# Site fica responsivo no simulador de smartphone do PC, mas na prática não fica responsivo

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde

Estou com problemas em deixar meu site responsivo, pq ele está corretamente responsivo no simulador de PC (link abaixo)

**SITE:** https://natupot.000webhostapp.com/

**SITE VERSÃO MOBILE:** http://mobiletest.me/nokia_lumia_920_emulator/?u=https://natupot.000webhostapp.com/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém na prática não fica deste jeito, o meu smartphone reconhece o site como uma pagina inteira e ele reproduz o site como eu vejo no computador mesmo, oque faz as letras ficarem muito pequenas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço a quem ajudar e um feliz ano novo

Comment: experimenta colocar esta metatag no header: `<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>`

Comment: @Miguel Eu coloquei esta metatag, o site ficou responsivo, porém não aparece mais o scrollbar vertical (scrollbar-y) e eu não consigo mais "rolar a page" já atualizei o site com este comando, no meu celular não aparece o scrollbar, porém no simulador do PC aparece

Comment: Eu testei em dois celulares, o primeiro não liberou o scrollbar-y e o segundo funcionou conforme o previsto, obrigado! Porém preciso ter certeza que funcione na grande maioria dos celulares, não sei se existe uma forma de fazer meu celular funcionar corretamente

Comment: Talvez tenha algum overflow nos css como hidden

Comment: só tem o hidden para o scrollbar-x

Comment: Não faço ideia do que possa ser, pode ser alguma propriedade css mal aplicada, ou uma herança que não esteja prevista

Comment: Você usa que framework?

Comment: Entao, eu vou testar em outros celulares, acho q não está funcionando no meu pq meu celular é velho e deve estar com o SO corrompido, caso confirme eu vou concluir a dúvida